# Does Apache Ignite work on jre1.6

Tags: java, ignite

I am deploying ignite application on websphere8.5 which works on jre1.6. I wrote my code in jre1.7. For successful deployment, i changed websphere jre1.6 to jre1.7.
Now the issue is that production environment is stable on jre1.6 and stakeholders are not ready to change it to jre1.7

Can somebody please tell me whether ignite will successfully work amd deploy on jre1.6
I need immediate help.

Regards,
Shilpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache ignite official page says it is tested on JDK7 and above.

https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite <= 2.3 works on JDK 7 & 8

Apache Ignite >= 2.4 works on JDK 8 & 9